# How to use this Guesty Api and how to get data from it

Tags: stripe-payments

I m using guesty.com api.
Adding a a payment about reservation

see this link
https://docs.guesty.com/#update-a-reservation

anyone can tell me what is the 
"stripePaymentMethodToken" here

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a Stripe token you'll need to send a call to Stripe using Guesty’s public Stripe key: pk_live_P0FSIEtbwU1GSvgvEM3DYuUZ, than send the received object to POST  https://api.guesty.com/api/v2/guests//payment-methods

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thank you for your answer, but I believe the OP not only wanted to know how to get the `stripePaymentMethodToken` but also what it is used for.